# Jquery Validadion Plugin - Can someone help with a custom Validation!

Tags: jquery

Hi Guys i need some help with Jquery Validadion Plugin

I have an input box that gives the delay time form the calculation of two other input boxes.
if the delay time is more than 00:15 min i have to select a delay code from another select box.
eg:

```
    <script>
function tdiff(t1,t2) {
    var t1 = hour2mins(t1);  var t2=hour2mins(t2);
    var ret = mins2hour(parseInt(t2-t1));
    if(t2<t1) {ret=mins2hour(parseInt(parseInt(t2+1440)-t1));}
    return ret;
}

$(function() {
$("input.[rel=time]").keyup(function (b){ $("#delaytime").val(tdiff($("#arrival").val(),$("#scharrival").val())); }); 
});

$().ready(function() {
    $.validator.addMethod('delayCode', function(value, element) {
    // ???!!!
    }, 'Please enter your a Delay Code'); 


    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#timetable").validate({
        rules: {
            arrival: { required: true},
            scharrival: { required: true}
        }
    });
});
</script>
<form id="timetable">
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="arrival" id="arrival" rel="time"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="scharrival" id="scharrival" rel="time"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="delaytime" id="delaytime"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="delaycode" id="delaycode" class="required">
      <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02">02</option>
        <option value="03">03</option>
        <option value="04">04</option>
    </select></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Can someone guide me..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this.

$.validator.addMethod('delayCode', function(value, element) {
    return tdiff(value)
    }, 'Please enter your a Delay Code');

$("#timetable").validate({
        rules: {

```
        arrival: { required: true},
        scharrival: { required: true}
        delaytime:{delayCode:true}
    }
});
```

and write your logic in function tdiff

Comment: hi mahesh! really cant get! :( can you help

Comment: @user505790: you can write your logic tdiff() ie in the function do your logic ie calculate the delay time and if it is morethan 0:15 select corresponding value

Comment: ok thanks but i dont want to use the same function for the calculation, am trying something like that $.validator.addMethod('lookdelayCode', function(value, element) {
 
 var t1 = hour2mins("#delayCode01");  var t2=15;
 if(t1<t2) {return false;}  can you guide me?
 return true;
 
  }, 'Please enter your a Delay Code');

Comment: @user505790: you can write that code in to a separate function. If the value is more than 15sec return true else return false.                  and give the rule as lookdelayCode:true

Comment: thanks mate can you help on this because on submit fonction its working and here addmethod its not working $.validator.addMethod('delayCode', function(value, element) {
  var dtime = $('#delaytime01').val();
  var dcode =  $('#delayCode01').val();
  var dtmin = hour2mins(dtime);
        var maxmin = 15;
  var zeval = 00;
        if((dtmin > maxmin) && (dcode == null)){
            alert("Please Select a Delay Code");
            return false; // cancel form submission
        }
        return true; }, 'Please enter your a Delay Code');

Comment: @user505790: Change the code like this   if((dtmin > maxmin) && (dcode == null)){ alert("Please Select a Delay Code"); **return true;** // cancel form submission } **return false;**                               and give delayCode:true for one control